# Handling Scope between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, so I am pretty new to Angular...figuring things out...and I have run into a funky issue.

So I have one controller (X) that is basically an Add/Update/Delete of some simple objects.

I have another controller (Y) that is pretty darn simple, but is completely separate from X. In this controller I...err control...a header that has a dropdown of X in it that is visible on every page.

My question is...if I manipulate X..i.e. add another, then I want to refresh the dropdown that lives in controller Y. I have a handy refresh method in controller X, but when it gets called it updates several different scope variables.

I have tried having a service that is shared between X & Y, but the scope stuff is getting in the way. From what I can tell services don't really like $scope because it can be called from multiple different controllers and the scope gets really messy.

What am I missing?

Comment: Code's worth a thousand words...

Comment: Please share your code, JS as well as html

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a global variable, you can put it in `$rootScope`:

```
app.controller('xCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.init = function(){
        .......
        $rootScope.globalVar = ......;
        .......
    }
    $scope.change = function(){
        .......
        $rootScope.globalVar = ......;
        .......
    }
}]);

app.controller('yCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.use = function(){
        .......
        $scope.localVar = $rootScope.globalVar;
        .......
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting variables in the $rootScope can be a solution but usually is better to not pollute the $rootScope.

Creating a factory for storing data that have to be used across multiple controllers/components is the way to go.

For example creating a factory like this one:

```
app.factory('DataFactory',function(){
  var data = [ { name: 'item1'},{ name: 'item2'},{ name: 'item3'}];
  return {
    data: data
  };
})
```

And after you can use this data in a controller just injecting the service like here:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, DataFactory) {
  $scope.data = DataFactory.data;
});
```

A working plunker with data shared between two controllers is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkqLp1jIxMBo84weT2Qw?p=preview)